Reading an expanding list from a .txt file and breaking loop when an element is found. Also typing done when the first script is done
I am making a python code where one python script prints all of the rgb values, and another python script is constantly reading it. NOTE: They are both in separate python files! When the first script is done printing all of the rgb values I don't know how to print done when it is finished printing all of the values. Then I am working on the next script, reading the file, and I can't get it to stop even though I put done in the txt file. Please help me.
First File(Types RGB Values)
def generatergbvalues():
    rgb_values = []
    for r in range(256):
        for g in range(256):
            for b in range(256):
                rgb_values.append((r, g, b))
    return rgb_values

def run():
    rgb_values = generatergbvalues()
    
    # Print the RGB values
    for value in rgb_values:
        file = open ('Python/Color/colors.txt', 'a+')
        file.write(str(value))
        file.write('\n')
        print(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()

This prints the rgb values, everything is working well, but I need it to print done when all of the rgb values are hit.
Second File(Reads the RGB Values)
done = False
def read(done):
    file = open ('Python/Color/colors.txt', 'r')
    data = file.read()
    datalist = data.replace('\n', '/').split('/')
    print(datalist)
    i = "done"
    if i in datalist:
        done == True
while done == False:
    read(done)
    if done == True:
        break

It reads the colors.txt file well, but I am having trouble stopping it after it sees the word 'done'. It just keeps going on forever.
colors.txt(File that has all of the rgb values[Sample])
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 4)
(0, 0, 5)
(0, 0, 6)
(0, 0, 7)
(0, 0, 8)
(0, 0, 9)
(0, 0, 10)
(0, 0, 11)
(0, 0, 12)
(0, 0, 13)
(0, 0, 14)
(0, 0, 15)
(0, 0, 16)
(0, 0, 17)
(0, 0, 18)
(0, 0, 19)
(0, 0, 20)
(0, 0, 21)
(0, 0, 22)
(0, 0, 23)
done

This is just a sample of the colors.txt when there are 23 values and done in the code.

The done in read is local to that function, so changing it has no effect on the global done.

How would I make done global?

In read, you can't, since it is a parameter.

So should i change done into a word like no for when it isn't done and yes for when it is done?

Thank you. The reason I did this was because I was bored. But I will take that into consideration

Look at my final answer. I addressed everything I could think of regarding the issues with your attempt.

There is a lot to unpack here. I'll divide this answer into two sections based on the codes you provided. I am assuming you are begginer at python and I will try to structure my answer as such.
Producing the RGB list
Improving upon your code without changing it much, it could look like this:
def generatergbvalues():
    rgb_values = []
    for r in range(256):
        for g in range(256):
            for b in range(256):
                rgb_values.append((r, g, b))
    return rgb_values

def run():
    rgb_values = generatergbvalues()
    # Print the RGB values
    file = open("Python/Color/colors.txt", "w")
    for value in rgb_values:
        file.write(str(value))
        file.write('\n')
    file.write("done")
    file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()

Please especially note the following changes:

open the file once at the beggining, close it once at the end - that way, you are not making costly IO operations great many times
"done" can be printed simply after the loop that finishes when it runs out of rgb values

More advanced tips if you want to look into them later:

You can use with syntax for file opening to avoid the need to close it.
Python has a feature called generators that would let you create all the rgb values in more efficient way (without the need to assemble them all into a giant list beforehand)

Reading the RGB list
You are overcomplicating this part a lot. If your goal is to read the list and print the values, one by one, you can achieve it with something as simple as:
def read():
    file = open('Python/Color/colors.txt', 'r')
    data = file.read()
    for rgb_item in data.split('\n'):
        # do something with the data here
        print(rgb_item)
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read()

This will stop after the whole file is read.
Your code did not stop because done wasn't global variable, because you had typo in the assigment (== is comparison, = is assignment) and because each cycle read the whole file.
In the case you wanted to read the file line by line AND stop it any time you hit the "done" string, it would look like this:
def read():
    file = open('Python/Color/colors.txt', 'r')
    data = file.read()
    for rgb_item in data.split('\n'):
        # do something with the data here
        if rgb_item == "done":
            break
        print(rgb_item)
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read()

I feel like you are not quite sure with the concept of opening and closing files here, and I would advise further studying on that.

Thank you very much. I will also make sure to close more files.

I'm not sure I understood all of your question, but here's a solution for stopping the loop when it finds the “done” string :
def find_done():
   file = open ('colors.txt', 'r')
   data = file.read()
   datalist = data.replace('\n', '/').split('/')
   print(datalist)
   i = "done"
   if i in datalist:
       return True

while True:
   if find_done():
       break


My comments should mostly handle the explanation of what the code is doing. My only mention is that I changed the write and read logic to make it easy to convert the file into the same datatypes that you had before writing them.
# generator for RGB values
def rgbvalues():
    for c in range(0x1000000):
        # use shifting and masking to parse channels
        yield (c >> 16) & 0xFF, (c >> 8) & 0xFF, c & 0xFF

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('Python/Color/colors.txt','a+') as file:
        # write each color as it is generated
        for values in rgbvalues():
            # write value as CSV
            file.write(f'{",".join(values)}\n')
            
        # colors have completed, write "done"
        file.write("done")

def read():
    with open('Python/Color/colors.txt','r') as file:
        # store each line, except "done", and determine if done
        datalist, done = [], False
        for line in file:
            if not (done := line.startswith("done")):
                # parse data back to tuples of int and append
                datalist.append(tuple(map(int, line.strip().split(","))))
    
    # return data based on the state of done   
    return datalist if done else None

# keep reading the file until `read` is not None        
while not (datalist := read()):
    # do nothing
    ...
    
print(datalist)

